# Issuing commands over Spring Integration SFTP adapter

Tags: ssh, sftp, spring-integration

Is it possible to interact with a remote system by issuing command line instructions, for example running a script that returns some output over SSH using the Spring SFTP integration?

Or alternatively, is there a Spring Integration adapter available or in progress for SSH?

Answer (score 0):

SFTP Outbound Gateway supports limited commands like
ls,get,mget,rm
here is the link:http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html